# Group Mysql Query With Nested Format

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, cross-reference

I've searched through older threads but haven't yet found a solution for the following issue: is it possible to group and arrange mysql results without resorting to nested queries?

Please see the sample below.

I have:

```
Month Jan, Location USA, Program DDD
Month Jan, Location UK, Program EEE
Month Jan, Location USA, Program LLL
Month FEB, Location UAE, Program EEE
Month FEB, Location USA, Program DDD
Month FEB, Location UK, Program MMM
Month MAR, Location USA, Program FFF
Month MAR, Location UAE, Program FFF
Month MAR, Location UK, Program FFF
```

I want them to display like this:

```
                +---------++---------++---------+
                |Month Jan||Month Feb||Month Mar|
+---------------+---------++---------++---------+
|Location USA   |         ||         ||         |
+---------------+---------++---------++---------+
|               |DDD      ||DDD      ||FFF      |
+---------------+---------++---------++---------+
|               |EEE      ||         ||         |
+---------------+---------++---------++---------+
|               |LLL      ||         ||         |
+---------------+---------++---------++---------+
|Location UK    |         ||         ||         |
+---------------+---------++---------++---------+
|               |EEE      ||MMM      ||FFF      |
+---------------+---------++---------++---------+
|Location UAE   |         ||         ||         |
+---------------+---------++---------++---------+
|               |         ||EEE      ||FFF      |
+---------------+---------++---------++---------+
```

I have tried grouping the query but I'm unable to render it to the HTML table.

```
SELECT 
    event.`event_id`,
    event.`event_program_id`,
    event.`event_month`, 
    event.`event_location_id`,
    location.`location_name`,
    program.`program_name`,
    program.`program_shortname`
FROM 
    `event`
LEFT JOIN
    `location`
ON
    event.`event_location_id` = location.`location_id`
LEFT JOIN
    `program`
ON
    event.`event_program_id` = program.`program_id`;
```

Right now its listing like this:

```
    column1 column2 column3
line1   34              
line2   34              
line3           34  
line5       34
```

Where I wanted like this:

```
    column1 column2 column3 
line1   34      34
                34      34
                34        

line2   34
        34      34      34              
line3           34      
line5       34
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do some inner queries to achieve this for each column, if you have a predefined number of columns in the expected result, something like just the months of the year.

I had some experience with reports based on SQL that used subqueries like this, at the end of the day, this solution preved to be a pain to manage :) today I just read the data, store in a matrix in memory and at the end generate the result based on the matrix, much easier to change in the future.

cheers !

here is an example in PHP

```
<pre>
<?php
$columns = array();
$data = array();

// add the data from the database
$data["line1"]["column1"] += 34;
$data["line2"]["column1"] += 34;
$data["line3"]["column4"] += 34;
$data["line5"]["column2"] += 34;

$data["line1"]["column1"] += 34;
$data["line3"]["column4"] += 34;

// find the columns
foreach ($data as $line => $column) {
    foreach ($column as $cname => $value) {
        if( ! in_array($cname, $columns) ){
            $columns[] = $cname;
        }
    }
}

sort($columns);

// display column names
echo " \t";
foreach ($columns as $index => $cname) {
    echo $cname . "\t";
}
echo "\n";

// display the data
foreach ($data as $line => $column) {
    echo $line . "\t";
    foreach ($columns as $index => $cname) {
        echo $column[$cname] . "\t";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
?>
</pre>
```

Here's another way to solve the problem

```
<pre>
<?php
$columns = array();
$data = array();

// add the data from the database
// sort the data in the SQL
$data[] = array("l" => "line1", "c"=> "column1", "v" => "AAA");
$data[] = array("l" => "line1", "c"=> "column1", "v" => "BBB");
$data[] = array("l" => "line1", "c"=> "column3", "v" => "CCC");
$data[] = array("l" => "line2", "c"=> "column2", "v" => "AAA");
$data[] = array("l" => "line3", "c"=> "column2", "v" => "AAA");

// find the columns
foreach ($data as $line => $column) {
    if( ! in_array($column["c"], $columns) ){
        $columns[] = $column["c"];
    }
}

sort($columns);

// display column names
echo " \t";
foreach ($columns as $index => $cname) {
    echo $cname . "\t";
}
echo "\n";

$name = '';
$count = 0;
// display the data
foreach ($data as $line => $column) {
    if( $column['l'] == $name ){
        $count ++;
    } else {
        $name = $column['l'];
        $count = 0;
    }

    if( $count == 0 ){
        echo $name . "\t";
    } else {
        echo " \t";
    }   

    foreach ($columns as $index => $cname) {
        if( $column['c'] == $cname ){
            echo $column['v'] . "\t";       
        } else {
            echo " \t";
        }
    }
    echo "\n";
}
?>
</pre>
```

other reference using html as output

```
<table border="1">
<?php
$columns = array();
$data = array();

// add the data from the database
// sort the data in the SQL
$data[] = array("l" => "line1", "c"=> "column1", "v" => "AAA");
$data[] = array("l" => "line1", "c"=> "column1", "v" => "BBB");
$data[] = array("l" => "line1", "c"=> "column3", "v" => "CCC");
$data[] = array("l" => "line2", "c"=> "column2", "v" => "AAA");
$data[] = array("l" => "line3", "c"=> "column2", "v" => "AAA");

// find the columns
foreach ($data as $line => $column) {
    if( ! in_array($column["c"], $columns) ){
        $columns[] = $column["c"];
    }
}

sort($columns);

// display column names
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
foreach ($columns as $index => $cname) {
    echo "<td>".$cname."</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";

$name = '';
$count = 0;
// display the data
foreach ($data as $line => $column) {
    echo "<tr>";

    if( $column['l'] == $name ){
        $count ++;
    } else {
        $name = $column['l'];
        $count = 0;
    }

    if( $count == 0 ){
        echo "<td>".$name."</td>";
    } else {
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    }   

    foreach ($columns as $index => $cname) {
        if( $column['c'] == $cname ){
            echo "<td>".$column['v']."</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Some example could help me understand it better ;)

Comment: add the example ;) have fun !! in the example I add only 1 level, but you can add as many you need just by adding more dimensions to the $data array

Comment: Wow that's not an example, thats a perfect solution i believe ;).

Comment: Now its listing only single row from the array, how do we list the entire row at a time?

Comment: can you explain with an example ?

Comment: Instead of just adding a value the the cell at $data["line5"]["column2"], add an array and push values in the array. and instead of listing one value as it's here foreach ($columns as $index => $cname) { ... add another for outside of this one to iterate over the array you build, and then show the values in the column position.

Comment: will add another way to solve it, hope it inspires the real solution :)

Comment: This method is good with a line break, but when trying to literate this to a HTML table its not drawing well ;(. I guess i need to dig someother solution.

Comment: add an example with html, now have fun with the formatting with css :D

Comment: WOW thats nice :) Thanks ;)